# Nagios compilation problem in hardened OS

Tags: centos, compiling, nagios, hardening

I am trying to install nagios in hardened OS CentOS, but I can not:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/home/nagios-4.3.2':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

I already installed all gcc packages, but can not

any advice ?

Comment: Looks like /home may be mounted noexec; a common hardening option.

Comment: `mount | grep /home` could confirm

Comment: or `strace -ff ...` the configure and see exactly what was being run

Comment: /dev/xvdb10 on /home type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)     /  yes noexec ,thanks  , so can i make this as a exec and after this change again /home with no exec  ,what y think ?

Answer (score 1):

The core issue here was that the /home partition was mounted with the `noexec` flag, preventing the make/compilation process from running executables that it was creating.